# Django modelformset_factory: One more Form shown than there should actually be

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following model:

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

For that I made the ModelForm:

```
class PortfolioForm(forms.ModelForm):

     class Meta:
          model = Portfolio
          exclude = ['id']
```

I need many of those in one template so I am creating them in the Following way in my view

```
def portfolio_form(request, pk):
   ...
   PortfolioFormSet = modelformset_factory(Portfolio, form=PortfolioForm)
   formset =  PortfolioFormSet(queryset=Portfolio.objects.filter(pk__in=list_of_ids))
```

finally in the html I have this:

everything is working fine except that one more is shown in HTML than there actually are. I have verified them in the shell. There are 3 but 4 are shown.

I am displaying them in the table. I am positive that it is not the template.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to exclude `['id']` in a model form although I don't think it will have any effect. If I remember correctly, you need to include `{{ form.id }}` if you are rendering the form fields manually in the template, otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: You are right it doesn't make a difference. but it works fine still!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `modelformset_factory` uses `extra=1`. Set it to zero if you don't want any extra forms.

```
PortfolioFormSet = modelformset_factory(Portfolio, form=PortfolioForm, extra=0)
```

Comment: Thank you Alasdair, thats what fixed it!